# Error in C++ undefined reference to main

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I keep getting an error saying...

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [FuelGauge] Error 1
```

My project is below as well as my code and makefile. Also if you see any other coding errors feel free to point them out =]

[image]

**Simulator Class**

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include "FuelGauge.h"
 #include "Odometer.h"

 using namespace std;

 int main(){
    FuelGauge fuel(0); return 0; 
 }
```

**FuelGauge class**

```
#include "FuelGauge.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
void FuelGauge::incrementGas(int gas){
    if(currentFuel < maxGallon) {
        currentFuel++;
    }
}
int FuelGauge::getGas(){
    return currentFuel;
}
```

**FuelGauge.h**

```
class FuelGauge {

private: 
            int currentFuel;
            int maxGallon;

public:
            void incrementGas(int);
            int getGas();           
};
```

**Odometer class**

```
#include "FuelGauge.h"
#include "Odometer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

private: int currentMileage;
Odometer::Odometer(){
    mileage = 0;
    Fuelgauge g;
}

int Odometer::getMileage(){
    return mileage;
}

void Odometer::incrementMileage(){
    if(mileage <= 999999){
    mileage++;
}
else{
    mileage = 0;
}

void Odometer::decreaseMileage(){

    if(g.currentFuel > 24){
        g.currentFuel--;
    }
 }
}
```

**Odometer.h**

```
class Odometer{

private:
    int mileage;
    int gallons;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
FLAGS = -Wall
CC = g++
SYMBOLS = -g

all: FuelGauge Odometer CarSimulatorDemo

FuelGauge: FuelGauge.cpp FuelGauge.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(SYMBOLS) -o $@ FuelGauge.cpp
Odometer: Odometer.cpp Odometer.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(SYMBOLS) -o $@ Odometer.cpp    
CarSimulatorDemo: CarSimulatorDemo.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(SYMBOLS) -o $@ CarSimulatorDemocpp
clean:
    rm FuelGauge Odometer CarSimulatorDemo
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for something that seems to be you forgot to link the compiled version of your `main()` function into the final executable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're getting is probably not because of your c++ code but rather your Makefile. You want to compile each of your cpp files rather to a object file than the separate application and then link them together into single app. To compile cpp to the .o file use `-c` option.

To sum up your Makefile should be as follows:

```
FLAGS = -Wall
CC = g++
SYMBOLS = -g

all: app

app: FuelGauge.o Odometer.o CarSimulatorDemo.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(SYMBOLS) *.o -o app
FuelGauge.o: FuelGauge.cpp FuelGauge.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(SYMBOLS) -c -o FuelGauge.o FuelGauge.cpp
Odometer.o: Odometer.cpp Odometer.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(SYMBOLS) -c -o Odometer.o Odometer.cpp    
CarSimulatorDemo.o: CarSimulatorDemo.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(SYMBOLS) -c -o CarSimulatorDemo.o CarSimulatorDemo.cpp
clean:
    rm FuelGauge.o Odometer.o CarSimulatorDemo.o app
```

**Remember** to change spaces in your Makefile to tabulators!

PS. `#ifndef` should always imply using `#endif` and in header files always use them!

Answer (score 0):

Your Odometer.h does not end in `#endif`. Since it has already been included through FuelGauge.h, `ODOMETER_H` is defined and everything after `#ifndef` is not compiled (preprocessor expands it to whitespace). Including the function `main`.

Comment: Wow great, I saw an example that had the #endif in the book so I thought I needed to add it in.

Comment: I removed the #endif statements and #ifndef ODOMETER_H & #define ODOMETER_H. But the error still is occuring.

Comment: Please bring those statements back. Additionally, put an `#endif` at the end of Odometer.h.